# Rotation for some elements

Tags: android-layout, android, android-orientation

I am trying to do thing that is already done in default Android 2.3 camera application - rotation only for some elements (such as buttons) when changing orientation of the device.
For example, when I switch my phone to landscape orientation I don't need to change whole layout - I only need to rotate some UI elements.
Don't know about Camera application in Android 4, but in Android 2.2 it looks the same as I want.
Is it possible?

(and sorry for bad English, guys)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I've just stumbled across it by accident. In case anybody finds this and is stumped there are two easy solutions. Your elements support a 'rotate' attribute which can do most of the hard work for it (just set an angle), but beware this seems to change the canvas dimensions and can leave you with empty padding. There is also a [Rotate Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html) which will help you rotate other drawables.